# Is recursion a effective way to do this?

Tags: android, recursion

I've written a code that shows an array of strings using `TextView` and `Animator`.
Is there a better way to do this? This is my code:

```
class TextViewAnimator {
    private TextView textView;
    private String[] strings;
    private boolean autoRemove;
    private int pos = 0;
    TextViewAnimator(TextView textView, String[] strings,boolean autoRemove) {
        this.textView = textView;
        this.strings = strings;
        this.autoRemove = autoRemove;
    }
    void startAnimation() {
        if(pos < strings.length) {
            textView.setText(strings[pos]);
            textView.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(700).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    textView.animate().alpha(0.0f).setStartDelay(700).setDuration(700).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            pos++;
                            startAnimation();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if(autoRemove) ((ViewGroup)textView.getParent()).removeView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't your if() condition replaced with while loop without need of recursion

Comment: This looks like it could lead to an infinite loop which keeps adding listeners.  Does this code even run without error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Haven't had any errors in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe more readable code.

**JAVA**

```
class TextViewAnimator extends AnimatorListenerAdapter {

    private TextView textView;
    private String[] strings;
    private Boolean autoRemove;
    private int pos = 0;

    TextViewAnimator(TextView textView, String[] strings,boolean autoRemove) {
        this.textView = textView;
        this.strings = strings;
        this.autoRemove = autoRemove;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        if (textView.getAlpha() == 1.0f) {
            animateLine(textView, 0.0f);
        }
        if (textView.getAlpha() == 0.0f) {
            pos++;
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    private void animateLine(TextView textview, Float alpha) {
        textview.animate()
                .alpha(alpha)
                .setStartDelay(700)
                .setDuration(700)
                .setListener(this);
    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        if (pos < strings.length) {
            textView.setText(strings[pos]);
            animateLine(textView, 1.0f);
        } else {
            if (autoRemove) ((ViewGroup) textView.getParent()).removeView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

**KOTLIN**

```
class TextViewAnimator(private val textView: TextView, 
                       private val strings: Array<String>, 
                       private val autoRemove: Boolean) : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
        if (textView.alpha == 1.0f) {
            textView.animateLine(0.0f)
        }
        if (textView.alpha == 0.0f) {
            pos++
            startAnimation()
        }
    }

    private fun TextView.animateLine(alpha: Float) {
        animate()
            .alpha(alpha)
            .setStartDelay(700)
            .setDuration(700)
            .setListener(this@TextViewAnimator)
    }

    private var pos = 0
    private fun startAnimation() {
        if (pos < strings.size) {
            textView.text = strings[pos]
            textView.animateLine(1.0f)
        } else {
            if (autoRemove) (textView.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(textView)
        }
    }
}
```